# Implementing Stream<T> which can be converted to Stream<U> where U is base of T

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I'm trying to implement a generic input stream of objects.  That is, an interface or a lightweight proxy to an implementation. Details of implementation are unknown, i.e. a user of my library can write its own stream of, say, protobuf messages, pass it to my library and get back, say, stream of strings or any other stream. I'd like to keep the interface of stream generic so that users can write their own transformations and build transformation pipelines.

The interface of a stream should look like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Stream {
public:
    T* input();
}
```

On each call, `input()` shall return a next object in the stream or a null pointer, if the stream is empty.

The problem is that I'd like `Stream<T>` to be convertible to `Stream<U>` if `T*` is convertible to `U*`.

My unsuccessful attempt was to use pointer to implementation like this:

```
class StreamImplBase {
public:
    virtual void* input_raw() = 0;
}

template <typename T>
class StreamImpl: public StreamImplBase {
public:
    void* input_raw() final { return input(); }
    virtual T* input() = 0;
}

template <typename T>
class Stream {
    StreamImplBase* impl;
public:
    Stream(StreamImpl<T>* impl): impl(impl) {}
    T* input() { return static_cast<T*>(impl->input_raw()); }
}
```

The constructor from `StreamImpl<T>` guarantees that the `void*` returned from `input_raw()` was acquired by casting `T` to `void*`, therefore `static_cast<T*>` is safe.

However, if I perform any conversion, this statement will not be true. That is, building `Stream<T>` from `StreamImpl<U>` is unsafe even if `U*` is convertible to `T*`.

So my question is, how do I handle this problem?

I see the next possibilities:

- store a converter (e.g. `std::function<T*(void*)>`) in the stream and update it on every cast. This seems unnecessarily expensive;
- store the result of `static_cast<U*>((T*)0)` and add this result to the pointer obtained from `input_raw()`. This seems unnecessarily dangerous;
- add the second template parameter `OrigT` and store `StreamImpl<OrigT>*` instead of storing `StreamImplBase*`. This will limit possible applications of the class, which I'd like to avoid;
- using `dynamic_cast` is not an option because one can't `dynamic_cast` from `void*`.

Are there any other possibilities? How do others implement something like this?

---

Here's a usecase. Suppose we have a protobuf message `X`. I'd like this to work:

```
Stream<X> stream = ...;
Stream<google::protobuf::Message> raw_stream = stream;
```

Again, I don't know how `Stream<X>` is implemented. All I know is that it contains a shared pointer to some implementation which generates messages.

Comment: @Justin I've updated my question.

Comment: You can't use a `Stream<T>*` pointer or `Stream<T>&` reference where a `Stream<U>*`/`Stream<U>&` is expected.  What you want to do only makes sense if a `Stream<U>` object is constructed from a `Stream<T>` object.  In which case, you would simply give `Stream<U>` an extra set of constructors/assignment-operators to handle `T`/`Stream<T>` as input.  But I don't think that is what you are looking for.  It would help if you would provide a [mcve] showing how you *want* to use `Stream`, but I suspect the answer is going to be "it won't work that way".

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've updated my question with an example. In this example I suppose that `Stream` uses pimpl so that I can convert streams without converting heavy implementation.

Comment: I've just realized that there is a pretty straight forward solution: create a stream implementation which would do the conversion and chain it to the original implementation. I'd say that I would like to avoid chaining implementations because it may be slow, but you may oppose that I already have two virtual calls and adding two more isn't a big deal.

Comment: @Zelta w-- yeah, you have just written what I have just been writing about. You are not able to perform downcasts with generic types, which means that the only way of it working is making user able to cast the stream of hypothetical X to a stream of any hypothetical Y, which is not a thing that generics can do, i.e. generic type derivation. So the only solution that would work is a, again, generic, transformer object that pipes a stream of one type to be interpretable as a stream of some other type.

Comment: But it's an amazingly interesting question, appreciated every second thinking about it

Comment: @IsaacCarolWeisberg the only problem with this approach is that (apart from adding more virtual calls) the chain of transformers can grow infinitely... Guess I can count number of transformers applied so far and if it become too large I can search for redundant transformations (i.e. casting from `X` to `Y` than back to `X`).

Comment: @Zelta "*Here's a usecase*" - you are trying to **construct** a new `Stream<Message>` object from an existing `Stream<X>` object, not access the `Stream<X>` object AS-IF it were a `Stream<Message>`. That is an important distinction to make, and one that I covered in my previous comment. What you showed is not a particular helpful use-case to show off your actual goal.  Please show a better example of how you intent to actually USE the streams.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I never said I want to use `Stream<X>` object as if it were a `Stream<Message>`. I've said I want them to be convertible. You're writing that I 'would simply give `Stream<U>` an extra set of constructors/assignment-operators to handle `T`/`Stream<T>` as input'. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Anyway, I think that the only possible solution here is the 'implementation chaining' discussed above. I'll write a full answer with an example later.

Comment: @Zelta: you can add different template parameters to class methods, eg: `template <typename T> class Stream { public: Stream(); Stream(const Stream &src); Stream(Stream &&src); Stream& operator=(const Stream &rhs); Stream& operator=(Stream &&rhs); ... template<typename U> Stream(const Stream<U> &src); template<typename U> Stream(Stream<U> &&src); template<typename U> Stream& operator=(const Stream<U> &rhs); template <typename U> Stream& operator=(Stream<U> &&rhs); ... };`

Comment: i'm intrigued to know why you declared `StreamImplBase* impl;` then you used it `StreamImpl<T>* impl` in your Stream class constructor, there must be an inheritance hierarchy lurked in the code.

Comment: @Zelta I can think of at least one more solution. If you just want to treat a `Stream<T>` as a `Stream<U>` similarly to string_view and string, then I think there are some tricks you can use for a better implementation.

Comment: @Zelta If you want to get fancier, you could then use SFINAE to enable the extra methods only if `std::is_convertible()` or `std::is_base_of()` says `U` is compatible with `T`.

Comment: @Abra001 yeah, sorry, missed the inheritance — fixed.

Comment: @Justin could you please be a bit more specific? What tricks are you talking about? `string_view` and `string` cannot be treated one as another, they just implicitly convertible one to another (actually, `string_view` explicitly convertible to `string`).

Comment: @Zelta please, no boher for sorrow, one here just needs to get as much informations from the other side to get him ready to generate an efficient answer,anyways i'd go aside remy's proposition and favor the usage of SFINAE, declare input as non void type like, `U*input_raw(){...}` because if you choose to declare it void you open a very large gate to whatever comes from anywhere, and this gets only resolved using a generic unsafe casting, which can runtime crash whenever an incompatibility occurs. .

Comment: I had this idea about using an integer offset to encode the operation that would be done by `Base* b = someFunctionReturningDerivedPtr();`, then using `std::function<void*()>` for the `someFunction` and adding/subtracting that offset to the return value + `reinterpret_cast`, but I don't think the language allows it, even though it makes sense in my head

Comment: Actually, if you can figure out a way to get the converter idea (`std::function<T*(void*)>`) working without also having to chain the converters, that seems better than chaining `std::function<Derived*()>` -> `std::function<Base*()>` -> `std::function<SuperBase*()>` -> ... . Because you'd be avoiding the linked-list of `std::function`s.

Comment: I strongly suspect standard C++ doesn't have a way to do this without chaining virtual or function pointer calls. (If only you could `dynamic_cast` from a `void*`. And I can think of an evil non-portable way that would work for the Itanium C++ ABI only...)

Comment: @aschepler technically, it is possible via `reinterpret_cast`'ing. See an [example](https://gist.github.com/AmatanHead/77b608921ef77dec8dea1fac532ce0e0). I'm not sure that this doesn't contain a UB of some sort though...

Comment: @Zelta A `static_cast<Derived*>(base_ptr)` is UB unless `base_ptr` actually points at a non-virtual base class of a `Derived` object.

Comment: There's an example very similar to this in the standard library: `shared_ptr`.  I suggest taking a very close look at how that class manages conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
template <typename T>
class Stream {
public:
  T* input();
};
```

is an object with one operation, which takes 0 arguments and returns a `T*`.

So is this:

```
std::function<T*()>
```

admittedly you invoke it like `stream()` instead of `stream.input()`.

With this second solution, if `U` is a base of `T`, then you can convert the above to `std::function<U*()>`.  Which solves your problem.

Personally I don't think typing `.input` between the name of your stream and `()` is worth a lot of work.

Type erasure that someone else has already done is best type erasure.

Comment: Yes you right! Replacing `Stream` with `std::function` is arguable, however, I've looked into the libc++ (llvm) implementation of  `std::function` and it does exactly what's @IsaacCarolWeisberg suggested, i.e. it creates an `std::function` which holds a reference to `std::function` which holds the original function... which makes me think there's no way to do that without intermediate calls. So each conversion would add at least one virtual call, interesting!

Comment: @Zelta Unless you have very deep hierarchies, I'm guessing it's not going to make much of a difference. Typical inheritance depths in my projects were 2 or 3 at max.

Answer (score 1):

There is one C++ feature that allows conversion from a derived class to a base class when the two classes are not known in the same function: exceptions. Naturally, this is an ugly, ugly abuse, but it works:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdexcept>

class StreamImplBase {
public:
    virtual void toss_input() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class StreamImpl : public StreamImplBase {
public:
    virtual T* input() = 0;
    void toss_input() override
    { throw input(); }
};

template <typename T>
class Stream {
    StreamImplBase* impl;
public:
    template <typename U,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U*, T*>::value>* = nullptr>
    explicit Stream(StreamImpl<U>* impl) : impl(impl) {}

    template <typename U,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U*, T*>::value>* = nullptr>
    Stream(const Stream<U>& str) : impl(str.impl) {}

    T* input() const
    {
        try {
            impl->toss_input();
        } catch (T* ptr) {
            return ptr;
        }
        throw std::logic_error("Stream logic is broken?");
    }
};
```

See a [complete example use on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4b2baad7f93b9ba). This could be improved by using `std::shared_ptr<StreamImpl<U>>` and `std::shared_ptr<StreamImplBase>`.

Comment: @Zelta Probably. I haven't done any measuring, but I wouldn't be surprised if the methods that chain calls to individual conversions are faster even when several types are chained.